# How to get all submatrixes(2x2) from any square matrix using function and then make a new matrix with maximum values from the submatrixes

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, submatrix

For example I have this  matrix(3x3) and I want to make a new 2x2 matrix with the max values from all the submatrixes :

```
  = [
     5 4 6
     3 2 3
     8 8 9
```

first submatrix:

```
[5 4
 3 2 ]
 max value=5
```

second submatrix:

```
[4 6
 2 3]
     max value=6
```

third submatrix:

```
[3 2
 8 8 ]
     max value=8
```

fourth submatrix:

```
[2 3
8 9]
max value=9
```

and I want to get this matrix(2x2) that has all the max values as elements of the previous submatrixes:

```
 NewA=[5 6
       8 9]
```

One last thing the only thing you can use are basic things like for loops if statements....(simple solutions,begginer solutions)
Also you can't use the max function,you have to write the code for that,and the solution should work for every square matrix

Comment: Do you have the Image Processing toolbox?

Comment: No I don't.I 'm not allowed to use anything too advanced.I need a begginer solution

Comment: Why wasn't that important information in the question since the beginning? Anyway, this looks like homework, so you should give it a try yourself, and ask if you get stuck

Comment: you're right.thanks for the effort

Answer (score 2):

### Using the Image Processing Toolbox

```
A = [5 4 6; 3 2 3; 8 8 9];
block_size = [2 2];
NewA = reshape(max(im2col(A, block_size, 'sliding'), [], 1), size(A)-block_size+1);
```

How it works:

1. `im2col(A, block_size, 'sliding')` arranges each sliding submatrix of size `block_size` as a column;
2. `max(..., [], 1)` takes the maximum of each column;
3. `reshape(..., size(A)-block_size+1)` reshapes the result into a matrix of the appropriate size.

Note that steps 1 and 3 both use [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), so the maxima in the result are arranged consistently with the input data.

### Without the toolbox

Using [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), `im2col`'s behaviour can be emulated as follows:

```
A = [5 4 6; 3 2 3; 8 8 9];
block_size = [2 2];
ind_base = (1:block_size(1)).' + (0:block_size(2)-1)*size(A,1);
ind_corner = (1:size(A,1)-block_size(1)+1).'+ (0:size(A,2)-block_size(2))*size(A,2);
ind_cols = ind_base(:) + ind_corner(:).' - 1;
NewA = reshape(max(A(ind_cols), [], 1) , size(A)-block_size+1);
```

The three variables `ind_base`, `ind_corner` and `ind_cols` have the following interpretation:

- `ind_base` defines the linear indices of the first (uppermost, leftmost) submatrix;
- `ind_corner` defines the linear indices of the upper-left corner of each submatrix;
- `ind_cols` contains the linear indices of each submatrix arranged as columns.

Answer (score 2):

Since the sub-matrices are `2x2` you can manually compute the max:

```
B = max(max(max(A(1:end-1, 1:end-1), A(1:end-1, 2:end)), A(2:end, 1:end-1)), A(2:end, 2:end));
```

or

```
B = max(cat(3, A(1:end-1, 1:end-1), A(1:end-1, 2:end), A(2:end, 1:end-1), A(2:end, 2:end)), [], 3);
```

If `A` is a square matrix both methods can  be written more compact as:

```
n = size(A, 1);
x = 1:n-1;
y = 2:n;
B = max(max(max(A(x,x), A(x,y)), A(y,x)), A(y,y));
B = max(cat(3, A(x,x), A(x,y), A(y,x), A(y,y)), [], 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using For-Loops (sliding window method)

Uses a set of nested for-loops to grab a neighbourhood of 4 (2 by 2). The position of the neighbourhood it relative to the variables `Row_Index` and `Column_Index` which are incremented/index the for-loop.

```
A = [5 4 6;
     3 2 3;
     8 8 9]; 
 
[Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns] = size(A);
Result = zeros(Number_Of_Rows-1,Number_Of_Columns-1);

for Row_Index = 1: Number_Of_Rows - 1
   for Column_Index = 1: Number_Of_Columns - 1

    Window = A(Row_Index:Row_Index+1,Column_Index:Column_Index+1);
       
    Maximum = Window(1);
    for Index = 2: 4
    if Window(Index) > Maximum
    Maximum = Window(Index); 
    end
    end
            
    Result(Row_Index,Column_Index) = Maximum;
   end
end

Result
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**